# Couldn't find file in a cloned .Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just cloned this ASP.Net project. I used the command line to create a new console (dotnet new console) and to run the application (dotnet run) and I was having this error. The application is working fine but it is not working fine on my system[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LtQc.png).

Comment: Which application you are running? Asp.net or console? Why you did create new console application?

Comment: please _copy_ the error messages instead of posting an image

Comment: `dotnet new` create a _new project_, potentially overwriting some existing files? If you already have an existing project, you should probably just use `dotnet run`.

Comment: Once you have properly cloned again the project, try to do a `dotnet restore` once, if `dotnet run` somehow still doesn't work. Seems most errors you get are related to external packages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chetan that was the mistake I made and I have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Might because of the dependencies which are not downloaded. Try using the command `dotnet restore` command in console at the location of your project. Or reopen the project in Visual Studio so that it automatically downloads the missed dependencies.

Comment: I have used the dotnet restore command and Is still not resolving.